# local access to samba share raspberry and dotnet 5

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, .net-5

I am running a raspberry pi and have setup a samba share.

I am deploying .net 5 app to the pi.

I want to be able to set a file share and use this path when deployed and running on the pi

What works, running the code on remote pc connecting to remote share:

//RASPBERRYPI/PiShare

//192.168.0.101/PiShare

**what does not work... deploying the code on the raspberry pi and trying :**

//RASPBERRYPI/PiShare

//192.168.0.101/PiShare

the pi can ping RASPBERRYPI so it can resolve its own host name, but ive even tried the pi.

what do i need to do so the pi can access its own share through code.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> _TestPathAccess(string filepath)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(filepath))
            {
                return JsonResponse(true, "Path was success");
            }

            
            return JsonResponse(false, "Could not read path.");
        }
```

```
[PiShare]
  comment=Raspberry Pi Share
  path=/home/pi/share
  browseable=Yes
  read only = no
  writeable=Yes
  only quest=no
  create mask=0777
  directory mask=0777
  public = yes
```

Comment: What OS does the Pi run?

Comment: @stickybit the pi is running raspberry

Comment: You mean Raspbian?

Comment: @stickybit https://www.kitguru.net/tech-news/christopher-nohall/raspbian-changes-name-to-raspberry-pi-os/#:~:text=The%20official%20operating%20system%20for,in%20a%2064%2Dbit%20version.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that yet. Raspberry Pi OS then. Either way, it's likely that you cannot access the share simply via an UNC path. You have to mount it first and the use the local path to the directory you mounted the share to.

Answer (score 0):

Extending comment given by @stickibit you can access a share from a pi with the following steps:

1. you need appropriate packages installed on your pi: `samba samba-common-bin smbclient cifs-utils`
2. you need to create a directory on pi under which you will mount the share you want, e.g.: `sudo mkdir /mnt/HereItIs`
3. you need to mount that share: `sudo mount.cifs //RASPBERRYPI/PiShare /mnt/HereItIs'` maybe some parameters required for username and password, see `man mount.cifs` for details

Now the contents of above share will be available under `/mnt/HereItIs`.

**BUT**: If the RASBERRYPI, where the share present is the same pi where from you want to access it why do you want to access it via Samba? Why not via direct folder access? If the `PiShare` your local pi sharing via samba is physically the `/home/pi` folder then simply use this path in your code (after making sure your code executor user can access it)!

Comment: everything you are saying is correct, but i was want to run the same code, from my machine or the pi and access the same share, and not have to change it depending on where its running from.

Comment: Try to use `/RASPBERRYPI/PiShare` in place of `/mnt/HereItIs` in my answer.